# One method multiple Interface return types

Tags: c#

Let's say I have

```
public class ClassA : Ione, Itwo
public class ClassB : Ione, Itwo
public class ClassC : Ione, Itwo
```

and a method MethodA that returns an instance of ClassA, ClassB or ClassC.
MethodA return type can be Ione or Itwo.

How can I achive that?.

I have tryed using generics like this:

```
public T MethodA<T>(myEnum e) where T : Ione, Itwo
```

but when typing `return (T)new ClassA();` I get the error "Cannot convert type ClassA to T".

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unite the two interfaces:

```
interface ITogether : Ione, Itwo { }
```

And use that as the return type.

You'll probably need your classes to implement ITogether instead of Ione and Itwo, but you should try both ways.

Comment: Thanks. This and BrokenGlass's are valid answers to solve the issue. As I was using generics just as an approach I marking this as the answer.

Answer (score 3):

You could define a new interface `IThree` that inherits from `Ione`, `Itwo` - then implement that interface in your concrete classes:

```
public interface IThree : Ione, Itwo { }
```

Then use this as return type:

```
public IThree MethodA<T>(myEnum e) where T : IThree
{
    return new ClassA();
}
```

To make this method generic you can add a `new()` constraint and return the type you want

```
public static T MethodOfType<T>() where T : IThree, new()
{
    return new T();
}
```

Comment: It's not possible otherwise - you won't be able to cast an instance of `A` to `T`

Comment: Mmmm, you are correct. Need to go sleep now. (btw, that makes the generics a bit a redundant, but then again the method usage is also questionable)

Comment: @leppie: I think the example threw us off - OP's `new A()` wasn't really needed in the implementation if it is truly generic, added to my answer.

Comment: Thanks. That's a nice solution. Using generics was just an approach I thought would work.

Answer (score 0):

First cast ClassA as an object

```
public T MethodA<T>() where T : Ione, Itwo
{
    return (T)(object)new ClassA();
}
```

should work, but can throw a runtime exception.  What you probably want is something like

```
public T MethodA<T>() where T : Ione, Itwo
{
    return (T)(object)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T));
}
```

Also note, this will still cause an exception if T does not have an empty constructor.  You can add a compile time check for this by adding updating the declaration to where T : Ione, Itwo, new()

Comment: This will explode if `T` is not `ClassA`.

Comment: Yea, I probably should have written that.  This is a bit dangerous as it could fail at runtime. I'm assuming he will always call this where T is typeof(ClassA).

Comment: just `return new T()` works with `new()` constraint being set - no need for `Activator.CreateInstance()`